# AdruinoBLE setManufacturerData not working?

Tags: arduino, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am using a NANO BLE Sense. I want to simply report its current values for temp, humidity etc with the least possible hassle. It was suggested that I use the manufacturers data in the advertising to carry the payload.

The problem is that is does not seem to work on any level.

```
  BLE.begin();
  BLE.setLocalName("AB1234567890");
  byte data[5] = { 0x01, 0x02, 0x03, 0x04, 0x05};
  BLE.setManufacturerData(data, 5);
  BLE.advertise();
```

I am seeing the local name displayed correctly, however when I look for the manufacturers data it is always empty.

My goal is to have a 64 byte string set inside the manufacturers data so that I do not have to connect. I have a use case for 20 devices, so connecting with each one will slow the system down.

```
  char Buf[64];
  advertisement.toCharArray(Buf, 64);
  uint8_t * u = (uint8_t *)Buf;

  BLE.stopAdvertise();
  
  BLE.setManufacturerData(0x6861, data, 64);
also tried
  BLE.setManufacturerData(data, 64);
  BLE.advertise();
```

Strangely, both with and without the 0x6861 above, it compiles which I would have thought was not possible.

Comment: Do you use the latest version of the Bluetooth Library? Seems that there was an issue in setManufacturerData() with earlier versions.
https://github.com/arduino-libraries/ArduinoBLE/pull/63

Comment: Yes, 1.3.1 according to the library manager.